# How to get/display the user-information after logging in. ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, ms-access

I am implementing an online voting system for my school-project.

After the voter's log-in, i want to display their name, and ID in the label control at the content body. I try to use SESSION to store the voter's username in the log-in page but I'm not sure of my syntax because nothings happen.

I want to know the other way of retrieving a data from database! Please teach me.

```
public void GetInformation()
{

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE voter_name = '" + Session["VotersID"] + "'";
    OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if(reader.Read())
    {
        lblVoterName.Text = reader["usr_FirstN"].ToString() + " " + reader["usr_LastN"].ToString();
    }

}
```

Please Help Me. Thanks! -

Comment: If you using ASP.NET default membership provider, doesn't need to fetch from DB. You can get it fro Identity object from the Context

Comment: what is the syntax for that sir?

Comment: Hi, @Honey Maglangit , could you check if the Session["VotersID"] is not null?

Comment: Hello, @AngusChung , is there a way to call or get the property from other page or class?

Comment: You can use Request.QueryString to get your PARAMETER value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Honey Maglangit , what you use is PARAMETER not SESSION.

```
Response.Redirect("VoterPage.aspx?VotersID="+VoterUsername.Text);
```

So, you should get your VotersID by this way：

```
public void GetInformation()
{
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.Connection = connection;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE voter_name = '" + Request.QueryString["VotersID"].ToString() + "'";
    OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if(reader.Read())
    {
        lblVoterName.Text = reader["usr_FirstN"].ToString() + " " + reader["usr_LastN"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Try it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LogonUserIdentity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.logonuseridentity(v=vs.110).aspx) as follow

```
if (Request.LogonUserIdentity.IsAuthenticated)
   lblName.Text = Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
```

just add this namespace:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
```

then you can get LoggedInUserId by:

```
User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

Or

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

So you don't need to use session to keep UserId.

Also you can create Custom Identity and instead of save Username in Name property, storing custom string [Store User Data in ASP.NET Identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn818488.aspx)

Comment: But sir, the name to display should be their complete name which i manually enter  in the database so just retrieve the information. By logging in using their ID as username and LastName as password.

Comment: There are few ways for this approach, but maybe makes you confusing if want explain here.

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the data from ms access database?

Comment: There is no diff between SQL, Access, XML file or any other DB. Only difference in how to retrieve the data. But if you use MS Access then default MS membership provider should be customizing for Access

Answer (score 0):

**get session data and send to one page(register.aspx) to another page(user_home.aspx)**

```
        Session["remail2"] = txtemailsignin.Text;
        Server.Transfer("user_home.aspx", true);
```

**display the user-information after logging**

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["socailweb"].ConnectionString);
        string sql = "select * from tblUsers  where remail='" + Session["remail2"] + "'";
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        SqlDataReader sqldr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (sqldr.Read() == true)
        {

            lblVotersID.Text = sqldr.GetValue(2).ToString();
            lblVoterName.Text = sqldr.GetValue(3).ToString();


        }

        sqldr.Close();
        con.Close();
```

Comment: Thank sir @balajibran, But there's no display :(

Comment: It's alright.   @HoneyMaglangit                                                                               check your table (tblUsers ) which place VotersID , VoterName is set                 example :                                                                          if you create VotersID as first then use lblVotersID.Text = sqldr.GetValue(0).ToString();                                                                  if you create VoterName as next then use lblVotersID.Text = sqldr.GetValue(1).ToString();  then you will get display